# Issue updating state to reflect that the user is logged in. Navigating to '/home/ redirects me back to the login page even though state shows as true

Tags: reactjs

I have the initial login configured where a user is able to login and get redirected to home, however, I'm running into an issue updating the state using { useEffect }. The state [isAuthenticated] appears to be updating correctly after viewing the console (see screenshot below), however, when I try to navigate to '/home' the protected route restricts me for some reason.

**Console.log**

*False* represents the initial state of [ isAuthenticated ] and *True* represents the state after { useEffect } runs.

[image]

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./Components/Login";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import ProtectedRoute from "./Components/ProtectedRoute";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function setLoginStatus() {
      try {
        await axios.post("/checkIfSessionExists").then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
            console.log(isAuthenticated)
          } else {
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
      
    }
    setLoginStatus();
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Login
            exact
            path="/"
            component={Login}
            setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            exact
            path="/home"
            component={Home}
            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ProtectedRoute.js**

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { Component, useState } from "react";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }
  />

);
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps of what happens which leads your code `to not work the way you expected`:

1. initially `isAuthenticated` is `false`
2. so the user will be routed to the `Login` component no matter what url they input
3. after the component was rendered, `useEffect` runs. you send a request and then set `isAuthenticated` to `true`
4. now the component rerenders, but the user stays in the `Login` component

The problem is that you need to reroute any users that are authenticated in to a different route (in your case, `Home`) after they were in the `Login` component to authenticate

The following example works and will do the following:

1. if the user is authenticated:

   - the user can navigate to the `/home` route
   - if they go to a different route, it will redirect them to `/home`
2. if the user is NOT authenticated:

   - the user can navigate to the `/` route
   - if they go to a different route, it will redirect them to `/`

I am using `<>...</>` which is equivalent to `<React.Fragment>`, which allows you to include adjacent elements in it, which is otherwise not allowed

```js
function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  ...  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {isAuthenticated
            ?
            // the user is autenticated
            <>
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
              <Redirect to="/home" />
            </>
            :
            // the user is not autenticated
            <>
              <Route path="/" component={Login} />
              <Redirect to="/" />
            </>
          }
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Is there a way to prevent the screen flash of the login page?